# R - Share of Records by Day of Week?

Tags: r, ggplot2

For those familiar, I'm working on the Coursera bike share case study . . .

I'm working in R and have a data frame that is a log of all rides taken with a bicycle ride share company.  A simplified version of the data frame is below.

| started_at | ended_at | weekday | member_casual |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-10 06:21:55 | 2022-11-10 06:31:27 | Thursday | member |
| 2022-11-04 07:31:55 | 2022-11-04 07:46:25 | Friday | member |
| 2022-11-21 17:20:29 | 2022-11-21 17:34:36 | Monday | casual |
| 2022-11-25 17:29:34 | 2022-11-25 17:45:15 | Friday | member |

I'd like to create a data frame (or better yet a visual - maybe a bar chart?) that shows share of rides by day.  So for example:

| weekday | member | casual |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Monday | 12% | 6% |
| Tuesday | 15% | 9% |
| Wednesday | 15% | 10% |
| Thursday | 13% | 14% |
| Friday | 14% | 18% |
| Saturday | 14% | 20% |
| Sunday | 17% | 23% |

[image: bar chart]

What would be the easiest way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

I tried creating a data frame but wasn't sure sure how to get percent share of whole by member_casual

```
weekday_by_member <- p12m %>%
    filter(member_casual=="member") %>%
    count(weekday) 
sorted_weekday_by_member <- arrange(weekday_by_member,levels = c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday","Saturday"))

sorted_weekday_by_member


weekday_by_casual <- p12m %>%
    filter(member_casual=="casual") %>%
    count(weekday) 
sorted_weekday_by_casual <- arrange(weekday_by_casual,levels = c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday","Saturday"))

sorted_weekday_by_casual


weekday_mem_cas <- p12m %>%
    group_by (member_casual) %>%
    count(weekday) 

weekday_mem_cas
```

[image: results]

Comment: Does it matter for how long they've used the bikes? For instance if we had only two users, one biking for 3 hours on Monday and another one biking for an hour on Thursday, would the percentage be the same (1 user on each day) or 75% Monday and 25% Thursday?

Comment: Please post the sample data or link of the dataset.

Comment: Instead of performing the filtering, you could try using the `group_by()` and `summarize()` function in the dplyr package.

Comment: @M-- good question.  I just want to know when the ride started.  So if a ride started at 11:50 PM Tuesday and ended at 12:15 am Wednesday - I'd count that as a Tuesday ride.

Comment: @AnilGoyal - the data is available here: https://divvy-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this.  Needless to say I am using it on one dataset only

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(weekday = lubridate::wday(starttime, label = T), usertype) %>% 
  summarise(trips = n(), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
  mutate(percent = scales::percent(trips/sum(trips)), .by = usertype) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = weekday, y = trips, fill = usertype)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label = percent), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), vjust = -0.9)
```

[image]

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(weekday = lubridate::wday(starttime, label = T), usertype) %>% 
  summarise(trips = n(), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
  mutate(percent = trips/sum(trips), .by = usertype) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = weekday, y = percent, fill = usertype)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(percent)), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), vjust = -0.9) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-02-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! This is awesome.  Is there a way to put the two usertypes on the same axis?  What I mean by this is that the bar height for Subscribers on Sunday (labelled as 8.06%) is higher than the bar height for Customers on Wednesday (8.47%).  I realize this is because the bar height is the number of trips and the labels are the % share.  How can the bar height be changed to the % share?   I tried to change the code to y=percent in ggplot but that did not work right.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response, please see the edit now

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite concisely using `xtabs`, `barplot`, and `proportions` for the percent labels.

```
> xtb <- xtabs(~ member_casual + weekday, dat)
> prp <- paste0(proportions(xtb)*100, '%')
> 
> b <- xtb |> 
+   barplot(beside=TRUE, col=c(4, 2), ylim=c(0, max(xtb) + 2), leg=rownames(xtb))
> text(b, xtb + 1, labels=prp, cex=.8)
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
> set.seed(42)
> n <- 100
> s <- sample(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct('2022-01-01'), as.POSIXct('2022-12-31'), 'secs'), n)
> dat <- data.frame(
+   started_at=s,
+   ended_at=s + sample.int(600, length(s))
+ ) |> 
+   transform(weekday=strftime(dat$started_at, '%A'),
+             member_casual=c('member', 'casual'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

df <- read_csv("202004-divvy-tripdata.csv") 

df %>% 
  mutate(across(started_at, ~ lubridate::wday(.x, 
                                              label = T, 
                                              week_start = 1, 
                                              abbr = FALSE))) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  aes(x = started_at, fill = member_casual) + 
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = percent(after_stat(proportions(count)))),
            stat = "count", 
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), 
            vjust = -1)
```

[image]